# How to get proper alignment when printing to file

Tags: c, file, unix, file-io

I have this Structure the elements of which that I need to write in a text file

```
struct Stage3ADisplay
{
    int nSlot;
    char *Item;
    char *Type;
    int nIndex;
    unsigned char attributesMD[17]; //the last character is \0
    unsigned char contentsMD[17]; //only for regular files - //the last character is \0
};  

buffer = malloc(sizeof(Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->nSlot) + sizeof(Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->Item) + sizeof(Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->Type) + sizeof(Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->nIndex) + sizeof(Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->attributesMD) + sizeof(Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->contentsMD) + 1);

sprintf (buffer,"%d %s %s %d %x %x",Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->nSlot, Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->Item,Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->Type,Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->nIndex,Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->attributesMD,Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->contentsMD);
```

How do I make sure the rows in the file are properly aligned.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "properly aligned"?

Comment: The way you calculate the buffer size is deeply flawed. `sizeof` won't tell you the size of the fields when converted to character strings.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I was using the sizeof function on the actual elements of the populated structure and not the structure definition itself. Would it still be flawed that way?

Comment: It's still flawed. The result of `sizeof(int)` is the size of an integer variable, not how many characters it would take to display the stored value. An `int` that contains the value `1` is the same size when it contains `1000000` but the printed output length is different.  Similarly, `sizeof(char*)` is the size of the pointer, not the length of the null-terminated string it points to.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, what should I need to do to find the actual printed output length?

Comment: There are non-portable ways to determine the __exact__ buffer length needed such as Microsoft's `_vscprintf()`. It may be simpler to just provide a "sufficiently large" buffer and then use `snprintf()` to avoid overflowing the buffer by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question relates to sprintf ,

Change

```
 sprintf (buffer,"%d %s %s %d %x %x"
```

to

```
 sprintf (buffer,"%22.22d %22.22s %22.22s %22.22d %22.22x %22.22x"
```

to see how  %nn.nn works.

Comment: I tried using the nn.nn method but however I get a segmentation fault. I believe this is because when I do %22.22s on the string, the string length is lesser than 22 in some situations. The thing is I cannot determine the length of the string at run-time but I am fairly sure it is always under 10 characters or fewer. Is there a way to make it more dynamic but have it properly aligned?

Comment: strlen() returns the length of a string.

Comment: Also, using "%[flags][width][.precision][length]" specifier
  is not causing the seg fault.  You have multiple problems.  Test with string constants until you get sprinf working to format your data.  Read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Also, use  "char * buffer = (char *)malloc(2222);" as the sprintf buffer until you get sprintf() and strlen() under your belt.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I found the answer I was looking for. Since I knew the expected maximum value a string can take from the test data,even though I used char pointer, I left aligned the fields by a specified limit.

```
buffer = malloc(sizeof(Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->nSlot) + sizeof(Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->Item) + sizeof(Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->Type) + sizeof(Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->nIndex) + sizeof(Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->attributesMD) + sizeof(Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->contentsMD) + 1 + 53);

sprintf (buffer,"%-3d %-10s %-10s %-10d %-10x %-10x",Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->nSlot, Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->Item,Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->Type,Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->nIndex,Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->attributesMD,Stage3ADisplayVar[nIterator]->contentsMD);
```

Comment: Instead of adding a fudge factor of 53 to your flawed buffer length calculation you could just decide on a reasonable maximum value and say `buffer = malloc(120);`. Note, I made up the value 120 for this example.